# Predicate testing for equality that returns the common element

Tags: clojure

I'm going to try brute-forcing the solving of a [Magic Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square). To simplify the code later on, I wanted a function similar to `=`, but one that returns the common element if all the elements are equal and `nil` otherwise. This is unlike `=` which always returns either `true` or `false`. I'm calling it `=?` for lack of a better name.

Example:

```
(=? 1 2 1)
nil ; nil because they're not all the same

(=? 1 1 1)
1 ; Returns the common element of 1
```

Obviously, this function won't work well when `nil` may be the sole element in a collection, since it will return falsey even if all the elements are the same, but `nil`.

I thought that there *must* be some kind of `core` operation I could use here, but after a few minutes of thinking, I couldn't think of any. I ended up rolling my own function using `loop`. I'd like general advice on the function that I wrote, or potentially a more idiomatic way to write it that I'm missing. It looks exceedingly clunky to me; especially after I realized the need for the `last-arg` accumulator. A recursive solution would be nice, as I fear I'm missing something obvious here:

```
(defn =?
  "Checks if every supplied argument =s every other.
  Returns the common element if they're all the same, nil otherwise."
  [& args]
  (loop [[f-arg & r-args] (rest args)
         last-arg (first args)]
    (cond
      (nil? f-arg) last-arg
      (= f-arg last-arg) (recur r-args f-arg)
      :else nil)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the single argument case. You can abbreviate to

```
(defn =?5
  ([] nil)
  ([arg & args]
   (reduce #(if (= % %2) % (reduced nil))
           arg
           args)))
```

However, the following is simpler still:

```
(defn =?
  ([] nil)
  ([x & xs]
   (when (every? #(= x %) xs) x)))
```

We can even fold in the zero-argument case in by destructuring, as you do in `=?4`:

```
(defn =? [& [x & xs]]
  (when (every? #(= x %) xs) x))
```

But this is too obscure for me.

Answer (score 2):

Soon after I posted this, I went for a walk and realized that this is the perfect opportunity to use `reduce`. I'm kind of embarrassed that I didn't see it originally, but this was my train of thought that lead me to what I'm much happier with.

First, I tried a simple reduction. This was pretty simple, although still a little verbose:

```
(defn =?2 [& args]
  (reduce (fn [acc n]
              (if (= n acc)
                n
                (reduced nil)))
          (first args)
          (rest args)))
```

I decided that this was probably simple enough to use a function macro for. Normally I don't like using them for reductions, but there's not much going on here:

```
(defn =?3 [& args]
  (reduce #(if (= % %2) % (reduced nil))
          (first args)
          (rest args)))
```

I don't like using explicit calls to `first` and `rest`, as I find they're usually neater when they're implicit in a deconstruction. I decided to deconstruct the arguments instead:

```
(defn =?4 [& [arg & rest-args]]
  (reduce #(if (= % %2) % (reduced nil))
          arg
          rest-args))
```

Then I checked what `=` uses, and found that it just uses multiple argument lists, so I tried that. This strikes me as the more idiomatic solution:

```
(defn =?5
  ([] nil)
  ([arg] arg)
  ([arg & args]
   (reduce #(if (= % %2) % (reduced nil))
           arg
           args)))
```

I'm torn between 4 and 5, but I think that both are a significant improvement.